# How can i insert mutiple row from another database by using values

Tags: mysql, database

When I enter this command, there will be an error because there are two rows in tbl_carts where email is ABC@gmail.com. Is there a way to take mutiple row from one database to another.

My sql command is:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_history(orderid, email, product_id, qty) VALUES
('testing', (SELECT email FROM tbl_carts WHERE email 'ABC@gmail.com'),
(SELECT product_id FROM tbl_carts WHERE email='ABC@gmail.com'),
(SELECT qty FROM tbl_carts WHERE email='ABC@gmail.com'))
```

Error Message is:

Subquery returns more than 1 row

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to do `INSERT` using `SELECT` values from other table:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_history(orderid, email, product_id, qty) 
SELECT 'testing', email, product_id, qty FROM tbl_carts WHERE email='ABC@gmail.com';
```

Here's a reference from the [official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)